# Hide button on one touch itself

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4.2

i want to hide button on one touch itself. when the user touches the button that button should get hide but on one touch.The buttons are moving randomly. The moving buttons shoul get hide on touch. i have done it but after two three times pressing only it gets hide. i am using touchupinside event. Can anyone help me?

```
-(IBAction)clickButton1:(id)sender
{
    if (button1.tag==1)
    {
        button1.hidden=TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        button1.hidden=FALSE;
    }
}
-(IBAction)clickButton2:(id)sender
{
    if(button1.hidden==TRUE && button3.hidden==FALSE) 
    {
        button2.hidden=TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        button2.hidden=FALSE;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide relevant code snippets ...

Comment: Please provide your code that you had written in TouchUpInside

Comment: means you want that the button which was pressed should get hidden and other buttons get visible right? Just tell me I will provide you solution..

Comment: @Marvin i want when i click on that button it should get hidden. but on one press itself not on two or three pressess. one this the button is moving randomly

Comment: then see my answer, It is working for one press

Comment: @Marvin  i forgot to tell the buttons are moving randomly.

Comment: It also working for moving buttons

Comment: @Marvin which one. I did not get you

Comment: Just try, plz use TouchDown instead of TouchUpInside, Its not solution but try it

Comment: Try and let me know as soon as possible

Answer (score 3):

Replace your code with this Button touchUpInside

```
-(IBAction)hide:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *tmp = (UIButton *)sender;
    tmp.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: Update your question first dear

Answer (score 0):

Replace your first IBAction method with this one:

```
 -(IBAction)clickButton1:(id)sender
{
  UIButton *button1 = (UIButton *)sender;
  if (button1.tag==1)
 {
   button1.hidden=TRUE;
 }
 else
 {
   button1.hidden=FALSE;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your button on viewDidLoad with loop

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{
     for ( c = 0; c < 10; c++ ){
           Buttons[c] = [[UIButton alloc] init];
           Buttons[c].tag = c;
      }
}
```

after that you can control the show hide with following code.

```
-(IBAction)yourActionMethod:(id)sender
{
    //your normal action codes here
    UIButton *tmp = (UIButton *)sender;
    if (tmp.tag == 0) {
          // some codes
    } else {....}

    //control buttons of the 

    for (int i = 0; i < tmp.tag; i++){
          Buttons[i].hidden = yes;
    }
    
}
```