# Button seems to only disable after multiple clicks

Tags: ios, swift, button

[image]

```
@IBAction func topButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let nicebutton = sender as! UIButton

    nicebutton.enabled = false

    let nopebutton = nicebutton.superview?.viewWithTag(102) as! UIButton
    nopebutton.enabled = true

    let hitPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    let hitIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(hitPoint)
    let object = objectAtIndexPath(hitIndex)
    object.incrementKey("count")
    self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([hitIndex!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    object.saveInBackground()

}


@IBAction func bottomButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    let nopebutton = sender as! UIButton

    nopebutton.enabled = false

    let nicebutton = nopebutton.superview?.viewWithTag(101) as! UIButton

    nicebutton.enabled = true
    let hitPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    let hitIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(hitPoint)
    let object = objectAtIndexPath(hitIndex)
    object.incrementKey("count", byAmount: -1)
    self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([hitIndex!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    object.saveInBackground()
```

I've tried to change up the tags to see if that's why, but alas, that has not done much. It's quite odd that this seems to be happening. Of course I'd rather it be disabled after one click.

Edit - tags

[image]

Comment: This setup works for me if `topButton` is invoked by a button with tag 101 and `bottomButton` is invoked by a button with tag 102. Are you 100% sure you have your tags and IBActions hooked up correctly?

Comment: Are you using TouchUpInside? Maybe another event type works better in your scenario, you could try TouchDown... Seemed to work for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101253/hide-button-on-one-touch-itself

Comment: @SteveWilford I believe so, note the updated post.

Comment: @NullPointer I may have to try that I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

What about setting it programatically?
Also, make sure you're using `touchUpInside` when linking your IBAction to the button click.

```
// In your code, set these as the IBOutlets to your actual buttons
var nice = UIButton()
var nope = UIButton()

enum MyButton {
    case Nice
    case Nope
}

func setAvailability(button: MyButton) {
    nice.enabled = (button == .Nope)
    nope.enabled = (button == .Nice)
}
```

Now, you can just call this function in you method calls:

```
@IBAction func topButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    setAvailability(.Nice)
    // ...other stuff
}
```

Comment: I tried this method, and while it didn't return any errors, it didn't work all too well. It looks like it should work however, the logic makes sound sense.

Comment: In what way didn't it work? Also maybe try putting the `.enabled = ...` inside  a background thread, maybe it's not updating the UI quick enough?